# Any recommended Independent Sound Libraries?

Tags: sound-libraries

Do you know of any high quality independent sound libraries out there?

I am especially looking for hard to find, independent libraries that may even be unreleased.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: freesound.org (already mentioned by qubodup below) has an immense repository of sounds, both musical and non musical. Some sounds are organized in libraries, but most of the aren't and formats and quality vary a lot. So a good search place if you're looking for something specific, but will not give the commodity a fully integrated library.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [www.asoundeffect.com](http://www.asoundeffect.com/), I think it's exactly what you're looking for. It's essentially a website for 'indie' sound effect creators / recordists to sell their effects.

The website tagline is "Welcome to the place for independent sound effects" :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you for excactly? There are so many libraries out there. I remember. @renecoronado recorded the uptown troley in SF for a kickstarter campaign. And the "sound collectors club" is a closes group which only gives access to tjeir libraries when you are a member and if you record sounds into their linraries, too. I'm member and it's super affordable!

Answer (score 0):

only if you want to shell out  over $300 for something that *may* just be a collection of loops and not even a usable font.

I use *TimGmbH* for my midis and *Viena* to build new sf's.

all brass voices currently sound awful. I'm working on it-- but it will take time.

....and +1 for good q!

**answer - it doesnt exist - not open-source -- *not yet.***

edit - creating sf's is harder than I expected, but anyway, regarding the legality question...I believe if I'm using my own chops to create individual pitches using instruments that I own & then give it away for free? I think im on faiurly solid ground, legally. I think the legal question may be confusing fonts with LOOPS; yes, if I didn't personally compose a loop I would not publish it. Fonts are singular notes and as far as I know no one has a trademark on A 440 (but ill check just to be sure!)

Comment: So you are making a soundfont using vienna samples? Will you sell? I just question the legality of this for anything other than personal use

Comment: I started on one, it was going to be for my Kanstul Baritone Bugle (in G) turns out it is hard to map recorded tones to keyboard locations (correctly, perhaps my recording equipment needs an upgrade) if I ever finish my brass soundfont I will give away v1 and add a small fee too download v2 if v1 is successfull.

Answer (score -1):

The independent, high quality [1985 Mercedes 190e-16V car sound pack](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/69968530/record-audio-of-a-car-via-dyno-for-use-in-racing-v/description) by Track Time Audio is exclusively available to the 37 backers of its 2012 Kickstarter project.

It is a 96KHz 24bit wav, 6.7GB zip release.

A small 490MB zip subset is available under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) terms on [Freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/people/Chippy569/packs/9658/).